# websphere application server

Tags: websphere-6.1

What is the exact use of this bellow entry in WAS6.1 server.xml. Can you please tell me why we need this "defaultCookieSettings" and his attribut "secure=false".

defaultCookieSettings xmi:id="Cookie_1282579260990" domain="" maximumAge="-1" secure="false"

```
 <components xmi:type="applicationserver.webcontainer:WebContainer" xmi:id="WebContainer_1282579260990" enableServletCaching="false" disablePooling="false">
      <stateManagement xmi:id="StateManageable_1282579260993" initialState="START"/>
      <services xmi:type="applicationserver.webcontainer:SessionManager" xmi:id="SessionManager_1282579260990" enable="true" enableUrlRewriting="false" enableCookies="true" enableSSLTracking="false" enableProtocolSwitchRewriting="false" sessionPersistenceMode="NONE" enableSecurityIntegration="false" allowSerializedSessionAccess="false" maxWaitTime="5" accessSessionOnTimeout="true">
        <defaultCookieSettings xmi:id="Cookie_1282579260990" domain="" maximumAge="-1" secure="false"/>
        <sessionDatabasePersistence xmi:id="SessionDatabasePersistence_1282579260990" datasourceJNDIName="jdbc/Sessions" userId="db2admin" password="{xor}Oz1tPjsyNjE=" db2RowSize="ROW_SIZE_4KB" tableSpaceName=""/>
        <tuningParams xmi:id="TuningParams_1282579260990" usingMultiRowSchema="false" maxInMemorySessionCount="1000" allowOverflow="true" scheduleInvalidation="false" writeFrequency="TIME_BASED_WRITE" writeInterval="10" writeContents="ONLY_UPDATED_ATTRIBUTES" invalidationTimeout="30">
          <invalidationSchedule xmi:id="InvalidationSchedule_1282579260990" firstHour="14" secondHour="2"/>
        </tuningParams>
      </services>
    </components>
```

If I change into from  secure="true" then what will be the impact

Answer (score 3):

The setting will specify that the session cookies include the secure field. Enabling the feature restricts the exchange of cookies to HTTPS sessions only.